# Why does my date format function only work when I use single quotes?

Tags: php

Here is date format function in PHP.

```
function formatMyDateNicely($strTimeString) {
    return date('F j, y \a\t g:iA', strtotime($strTimeString));   
}
```

It outputs a date akin to "April 23, 12 at 12:01PM".

However, this function, which uses double quotes, does not work.

```
function formatMyDateNicely($strTimeString) {
    return date("F j, y \a\t g:iA", strtotime($strTimeString));   
}
```

This function outputs a date akin to "April 23, 12 a 12:01PM".

Why does changing the type of quotes matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\t` is a tab character. Single quotes inhibit interpretation of escape sequences.

Answer (score 2):

It's treating the `\t` as a tab character because of the double quotes. Another alternative would be to "double escape" the `t`:

```
return date("F j, y \a\\t g:iA", strtotime($strTimeString));
```